# I need to create a query in SQL that contains fields from a table for records whose primary key in said table exist in another query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

query is named qryTour115Subquery and selects all HikerID's from a table named Reservation where the TourID is equal to 115 (HikerID is a foreign key in Reservation table)
Hiker ID is a primary key in Hiker table, which is the table I need to get fields from

Comment: That's really vague, so hard to answer.

Comment: If tables have relationship, build query that joins them. Exactly what is the difficulty you have in doing this? Edit question to show sample data and your attempted query SQL statement.

Comment: This is a simple select query google select query, ms access and then study.  Also check out the query designer in access.  It can be a lot of help for learning SQL..  In the end you will get something like SELECT * FROM Hiker INNER JOIN Reservation on   Hiker.HikerID = Reservation.ReservationID WHERE TourID =115 Anyway the question is too vague see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @mazoula, shouldn't the join be more like: `ON Hiker.HikerID = Reservation.HikerID`.

Comment: yip; too bad I can't edit a comment.  Maybe we could start deleting comments and reposting :)